# Can I subtract a value from a column of a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

If I have

```
listOfLists = [
   [123, "str1"],
   [234, "str2"]
              ]

listOfLists[:[0]] = [x - 15 for x in listOfLists]
```

can I perform an operation to subtract a value from just the [:[0]] part of the information?

The error I am getting currently is

```
can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
listOfLists = [ [x[0]-15, x[1]] for x in listOfLists]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to apply an operation to each member of a list. One way to subtract from the first element regardless of the length of each list would be like so:

```
>>> foo = [ [1, "a"], [2, "b", "c"] ]
>>> map(lambda x: [x[0] - 5] + x[1:], foo)
[[-4, 'a'], [-3, 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: map returns a new list, it doesn't modify the list in place. Were you setting your list with listOfLists = map(...)?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'd be looking to modify my existing list.